# checking out the process id of /sbin/init using ps and pgrep

Tags: linux

The following commands do not return any result

```
ps -C init -o pid=
ps -C /sbin/init -o pid=
pgrep -x /sbin/init
```

where as the following command gives output as follows:

```
$ ps -ealf | grep init
4 S root         1     0  0  80   0 -  6266 -      08:35 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init auto noprompt

$ pidof init
1
```

I would like to know how to get the PID of init process using **ps -C** and **pgrep** method. What I am doing wrong here?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with kernel 4.10.0-27-generic 32-bit

Comment: What distro are you using?  I get output as expected on my box.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with kernel 4.10.0-27-generic 32-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04, `/sbin/init` is a symlink to systemd:

```
$ readlink /sbin/init
/lib/systemd/systemd
$ sudo readlink /proc/1/exe
/lib/systemd/systemd
$ sudo xargs -0a /proc/1/cmdline
/sbin/init splash
```

`ps -C` reads the command name in `/proc/<pid>/stat`. See [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
/proc/[pid]/stat
      Status information about the process.  This is used by ps(1).
      It is defined in the kernel source file fs/proc/array.c.
      ...

      (2) comm  %s
                The filename of the executable, in parentheses.
                This is visible whether or not the executable is
                swapped out.
```

Since systemd supports re-executing itself as init (e.g., `systemctl daemon-reexec`), it tries to change this to `systemd` as soon as possible, if started as `/sbin/init`. From [the source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3046b6db1d285a7aba2247b48f0cc98372defab6/src/core/main.c#L2318):

```c
/* If we get started via the /sbin/init symlink then we are called 'init'. After a subsequent reexecution we
 * are then called 'systemd'. That is confusing, hence let's call us systemd right-away. */
program_invocation_short_name = systemd;
(void) prctl(PR_SET_NAME, systemd);
```

So, `ps -C init` will not match a systemd of PID 1. With `pgrep`, you can use `-f`.

```
$ ps -C systemd
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:01 systemd
 1261 ?        00:00:00 systemd

$ pgrep -f /sbin/init
1
```

`pgrep -f` checks `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, and systemd does not attempt to change that. The second `systemd` in the `ps` output is my user session init.

Answer (score 1):

Any system using systemd without sysvcompat will behave like this. Even though  /sbin/init is a link to systemd the command name is still systemd. When using the -C option of ps this will only look up systemd. When using the -f option of ps meaning full format prints the command arguments (args) instead of command names (comm) in the CMD column and indeed systemd is starting using the file `/sbin/init`

Try this command:

```
ps --pid=1 -o cmd,comm
```

Actually this would include other arguments as well if it had any and it also implies that arguments in Unix thanks to symlinks can lead to entirely different command names they point to.